# css on hover works for first 3, then doesnt. Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i am currently making footer images with a on hover effect.
The first 3 work just fine but the last 2 don't want to work.
I use the same exact code for the css and html, can someone help me.
This is the code i use for each one.

CSS Example:

```
.rssfade {
position:relative;
display:block;
height:32px;
width:32px;
background:url(images/social-icons/LinkedIn.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.rssfade span.hover {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
display:block;
height:32px;
width:32px;
background:url(images/social-icons/LinkedIn-c.png) 0 -0px no-repeat;
}
```

Html Example:

```
 <div id="bottom-social">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="rssfade" href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=325809071&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile"><span></span></a></li>
```

Comment: I don't see any `:hover` pseudo-class here, Do you toggle the `.hover` class by JavaScript? or what?

Comment: `background:url(images/social-icons/LinkedIn-c.png) 0 -0px no-repeat;` should be `background-image:url('images/social-icons/LinkedIn-c.png') 0 -0px no-repeat;`

Comment: I honestly dont know if its javascript or not, because i am using a template for wordpress, im gonna check though. And the background thing does not work

Comment: FOUnd it, thanks for mentioning that it was mayby in Javascript, because i found the hover code in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change `.rssfade span.hover` to `.rssfade span:hover`

You need `:` for pseudo elements to work

Comment: I'd surprised if `.hover` worked for the *first 3* then.

Answer (score 1):

give the `li` element class `.rssfade`

```
<div id="bottom-social">
    <ul>
        <li class="rssfade"><a  href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=325809071&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile"><span></span></a></li>
```

and also change `.rssfade span.hover` to `.rssfade span:hover`